# Validate hasMany relationship against another hasMany

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have 3 models: **`type`**, **`restriction`** and **`item`**.

A **`type`** is simple and just has an `id`:

`app/models/type.js`:

```
import Model from 'ember-data/model';
export default Model.extend({});
```

A **`restriction`** can have many **`type`** describing the allowable types for an item with this restriction:

`app/models/restriction.js`:

```
import Model from 'ember-data/model';
import { hasMany } from 'ember-data/relationships';

export default Model.extend({
  allowedTypes: hasMany( "type" )
});
```

An **`item`** can have many **`type`** but also can have many **`restriction`** and the **`type`** must only be a subset of the intersection of the allowed types for all the restrictions (and if there is at least one restriction then it must have at least one type).

I've implemented a validation for this using a computed property:

`app/models/item.js`:

```
import Model from 'ember-data/model';
import { computed } from '@ember/object';
import { hasMany } from 'ember-data/relationships';
import { isEmpty } from '@ember/utils';

const peekHasMany    = attr => ( item => item.hasMany( attr ).ids() );
const hasItems       = array => !isEmpty( array );
const includedIn     = array => ( item => array.indexOf( item ) >= 0 );
const intersectionOf = ( array1, array2, index ) => index >= 0 ? array1.filter( includedIn( array2 ) ) : array2;

export default Model.extend({
  types:        hasMany( "type" ),
  restrictions: hasMany( "restriction" ),
  isValidTypes: computed(
    "types.[]",
    "restrictions.@each.allowedTypes",
    function(){
      let restrictions = this.hasMany( "restrictions" ).value();

      if ( isEmpty( restrictions ) )
      {
        return true;
      }

      let allowed = restrictions
                      .map( peekHasMany( "allowedTypes" ) )
                      .filter( hasItems );

      if ( isEmpty( allowed ) )
      {
        return true;
      }

      let types = this.hasMany( "types" ).ids();
      if ( isEmpty( types ) )
      {
        return false;
      }

      let allowedTypes = allowed.reduce( intersectionOf );
      return types.every( includedIn( allowedTypes ) );
    }
  )
});
```

This uses the [`DS.Model.hasMany( attributeName )`](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember-data/3.1/classes/DS.Model/methods/hasMany?anchor=hasMany) to synchronously get the `HasManyReference` for the relationships which relies on the referenced models being loaded.

How can I change the computed property to use `this.get()` to asynchronously get both attributes (and the child attributes) rather than using `this.hasMany()` synchronously?

Comment: Have you considered using a library for this? something like ember-cp-validations? https://github.com/offirgolan/ember-cp-validations

Comment: @JoeHartzell If you want to put together an answer showing how my code can be re-implemented asynchronously using that library. However, from looking through the documentation, the custom validators are just JavaScript functions so, my initial take is that, a similar answer could be written with or without the library (but I may well be missing some functionality that makes it particularly easy using the library).

Comment: You initial take is indeed just that. But there is no reason to reinvent the wheel. Their library offers a lot when it comes to validation. And just being able to call "isValid" on an entire component or route or model is well worth the implementation

Comment: @JoeHartzell You appear to be missing the point - that library does not offer a way to validate one hasMany against another hasMany so even if the library is used a custom validator needs to be written - I am agnostic as to what framework that validator is written in - the question is **how** to write the async code within the validator.

Answer (score 1):

```
let value = this.hasMany( attributeName ).value();
/* following code */
```

can be replaced with

```
this.get( attributeName ).then( value => { /* following code */ } );
```

The complication comes with the lines:

```
const peekHasMany = attr => ( item => item.hasMany( attr ).ids() );
let allowed = restrictions.map( peekHasMany( "allowedTypes" ) )
/* following code */
```

Which, when changed will result in an array of promises. This can be wrapped in a single promise using `Promise.all( arrayOfPromises )`

```
const getAll = attr => ( item => item.get( attr ) );
Promise.all( restrictions.map( getAll( "allowedTypes" ) ) )
  .then( allowed => {
    /* following code */
  } );
```

The code then becomes:

```
import Model from 'ember-data/model';
import { computed } from '@ember/object';
import { hasMany } from 'ember-data/relationships';
import { isEmpty } from '@ember/utils';

const getAll         = attr => ( item => item.get( attr ) );
const hasItems       = array => !isEmpty( array );
const includedIn     = array => ( item => array.indexOf( item ) >= 0 );
const intersectionOf = ( array1, array2, index ) => index >= 0 ? array1.filter( includedIn( array2 ) ) : array2;

export default Model.extend({
  types:        hasMany( "type" ),
  restrictions: hasMany( "restriction" ),
  isValidTypes: computed(
    "types.[]",
    "restrictions.@each.allowedTypes",
    function(){
      return this.get( "restrictions" )
        .then( restrictions => {
          if ( isEmpty( restrictions ) )
          {
            return true;
          }

          return Promise.all( restrictions.map( getAll( "allowedTypes" ) ) )
            .then( allowed => {
              allowed = allowed.filter( hasItems );
              if ( isEmpty( allowed ) )
              {
                return true;
              }

              return this.get( "types" )
                .then( types => {
                  if ( isEmpty( types ) )
                  {
                    return false;
                  }

                  let allowedTypes = allowed.reduce( intersectionOf );
                  return types.every( includedIn( allowedTypes ) );
                } );
            } );
        } );
    }
  )
});
```

---

Or using the `async` and `await` syntax:

```
import Model from 'ember-data/model';
import { computed } from '@ember/object';
import { hasMany } from 'ember-data/relationships';
import { isEmpty } from '@ember/utils';

const getAll         = attr => ( item => item.get( attr ) );
const hasItems       = array => !isEmpty( array );
const includedIn     = array => ( item => array.indexOf( item ) >= 0 );
const intersectionOf = ( array1, array2, index ) => index >= 0 ? array1.filter( includedIn( array2 ) ) : array2;

export default Model.extend({
  types:        hasMany( "type" ),
  restrictions: hasMany( "restriction" ),
  isValidTypes: computed(
    "types.[]",
    "restrictions.@each.allowedTypes",
    async function(){
      let restrictions = await this.get( "restrictions" );
      if ( isEmpty( restrictions ) )
      {
        return true;
      }

      let allowed = ( await Promise.all( restrictions.map( getAll( "allowedTypes" ) ) ) )
                      .filter( hasItems );
      if ( isEmpty( allowed ) )
      {
        return true;
      }

      let types = await this.get( "types" );
      if ( isEmpty( types ) )
      {
        return false;
      }

      let allowedTypes = allowed.reduce( intersectionOf );
      return types.every( includedIn( allowedTypes ) );
    }
  )
});
```